# Master theorem with $T(n) = 6T(n/10) + \lg^2 n$

Tags: recurrence-relation, master-theorem

So I think this falls under case 1...but I am not sure how to formally prove that $n^{lg_{10} 6}$ is asymptotically greater than $\lg^2 n$. I tried using L'hopitals but kinda reached a dead end. Here's what i have so far

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{d(\lg^2 n)}{d(n^{\lg_{10}6})} = \frac{2 \lg n (\frac{1}{n})}{(\lg_{10}6) n ^{(\lg_{10}6) - 1}}$$

Is there some better way I can think about proving case 1?

Comment: Raise both to the power $\log_610$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting functions by asymptotic growth](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/824/sorting-functions-by-asymptotic-growth)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yuval Filmus pretty much showed the way in the comment above. I will just elaborate on his approach.

First, we raise both to the power **lg<sub>6</sub>10**.

### **(n<sup>lg<sub>10</sub>6</sup>)<sup>lg<sub>6</sub>10</sup>** = **n<sup>(lg<sub>10</sub>6 x lg<sub>6</sub>10)</sup> = n**

and,

### **(lg<sup>2</sup>n)<sup>lg<sub>6</sub>10</sup> = (lg n)<sup>2 x lg<sub>6</sub>10</sup> = (lg n)<sup>2.57</sup>**

Now, taking **log** of both of these, we get 
**lg(n)** and **2.57xlg(lg(n))** respectively.

**lg(n)** is asymptotically greater than **lg(lg(n))**, and thus, our case is proved.

Comment: Anyone who's unwilling to just accept that polynomial dominates polylog should also be unwilling to just accept that log dominates log-log. Essentially, you've just done some algebraic manipulations and asserted a fact that's essentially equivalent to the thing you're trying to prove.

Comment: @David Richerby, it's just as you said. But maybe the questioner has just started learning about time complexities? And, maybe s/he found my algebraic manipulations a bit easier to understand and that's why accepted the answer? Also, "log > log-log" is easier to grasp I think.